# Need api for gym exercice like api-ninjas

Tags: javascript, api

I am building a gym log tracker where I will put my exercice from gym. The problem is that I cannot find the one that offers pictures also.
I found https://api-ninjas.com/api/exercises but is offering only a limited info.

I am looking for something like exerciceDB, because the exerciceDB offers also images...

Comment: Why not just use exerciseDB then?

Comment: I am looking for one more affordable.. And since the exerciceDB is on rapidAPI platform, I did not found the original platform... That is my downside..